# Order status is not getting changed

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

When i am submitting the invoice from the admin panel for an order the order status is changed to processing from pending, but when i am submitting the invoice by using the REST API order status is still pending. 
Here is my api call url:
http://MYHOST/rest/default/V1/invoices

and payload is:

```
{
"entity": {
"baseCurrencyCode": "INR",
"baseDiscountAmount": -512.4,
"baseGrandTotal": 2054.6,
"baseDiscountTaxCompensationAmount": 0,
"baseShippingAmount": 5,
"baseShippingDiscountTaxCompensationAmnt": 0,
"baseShippingInclTax": 0,
"baseShippingTaxAmount": 0,
"baseSubtotal": 2562,
"baseSubtotalInclTax": 2562,
"baseTaxAmount": 0,
"baseTotalRefunded": 0,
"baseToGlobalRate": 1,
"baseToOrderRate": 1,
"billingAddressId": 24,
"canVoidFlag": 0,
"createdAt": "2015-12-04 12:07:29",
"discountAmount": -512.4,
"discountDescription": "string",
"emailSent": 1,
"globalCurrencyCode": "INR",
"grandTotal": 2054.6,
"discountTaxCompensationAmount": 0,
"isUsedForRefund": 0,
"orderCurrencyCode": "string",
"orderId": 12,
"shippingAmount": 5,
"shippingDiscountTaxCompensationAmount": 0,
"shippingInclTax": 0,
"shippingTaxAmount": 0,
"state": 2,
"storeCurrencyCode": "INR",
"storeId": 1,
"storeToBaseRate": 0,
"storeToOrderRate": 0,
"subtotal": 2562,
"subtotalInclTax": 2562,
"taxAmount": 0,
"totalQty": 1,
"items": [
{
"additionalData": "string",
"baseCost": 2562,
"baseDiscountAmount": 512.4,
"baseDiscountTaxCompensationAmount": 0,
"basePrice": 512.4,
"basePriceInclTax": 512.4,
"baseRowTotal": 0,
"baseRowTotalInclTax": 0,
"baseTaxAmount": 0,
"description": "string",
"discountAmount": 512.4,
"discountTaxCompensationAmount": 0,
"name": "VNR AG LONG",
"orderItemId": 20,
"price": 2562,
"priceInclTax": 2562,
"productId": 2066,
"qty": 1,
"rowTotal": 2562,
"rowTotalInclTax": 2562,
"sku": "VNR-AG-LONG",
"taxAmount": 0,
"extensionAttributes": {}
}
],
"extensionAttributes": {}
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your `"state":2,` to `"state":"processing",`?

Comment: state is numeric field, and also when i am submitting the invoice form admin panel its 2 i checked in database.